# Angular $viewValue avoiding some values

Tags: angular, filter, angular1.6

`uib-typeahead="school as school.en for school in mod.schools | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:100"`

I want to List all the values and filter the the matching strings while user typing.
above expression returns like values around 30.

But if `filter:$viewValue` is removed all the values will list down but unable to filter values.

`uib-typeahead="school as airport.en for school in mod.schools | limitTo:100"`

Any idea how can I have filter and list down all values?

Answer (score 1):

This is sorted. No issue with this line, it returns all values and filters correctly.

```
 uib-typeahead="school as school.en for school in mod.schools | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:100"
```

Just removed below line from input tag properties

```
typeahead-focus
```